# Making The Edit Control Transparent WinAPI (win32)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, controls, transparent

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    SetBkMode(HDC(wParam),TRANSPARENT);
    return LRESULT(HBRUSH(GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH)));
```

It makes the background all the controls transparent, including the edit ones. But when some text is typed, it overwrites on itself and looks messy. How should I reset the visible area and redraw with the current situation? Should I process something inside `WM_COMMAND`s `EN_CHANGE` or `WM_PAINT` or something else?

Here is how it currently looks:
[image]

Comment: It's doing exactly what you asked - the background is transparent, so anything written previously won't be erased when you type something new.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes but how can the previously written text be erased?

Comment: Usually that happens automatically, WM_ERASE is called with the brush you selected then the text is written with the same brush as the background. You've explicitly bypassed all that.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've declared a variable, `bool changing;` and it becomes `true` on `EN_CHANGE` then `WM_CTLCOLOR...` messages return something else than `NULL_BRUSH` in this case. So it erases background as usual. But it doesn't get transparent again, I'll edit the question to provide minimal reproducible example

Comment: @MarkRansom Can you take look again please?

Comment: @MarkRansom don't you mean `WM_ERASEBKGND`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau He does, anyway... I'm trying to make it transparent after `WM_COMMAND` is got with `EN_KILLFOCUS` now but it doesn't work. How can this be done, can you help me please?

Comment: @user814412 You can't simply erase the old text, you need to draw a new background over top of the old text, and then the new text gets drawn over top of the new background. If the background is transparent, you see both texts. Simple as that. You would have to screen grab the UI *underneath* your Edit control and use that as your new background manually, or subclass the Edit control to manually draw all of the text in `WM_PAINT`. In which case, you may as well just make a custom control from scratch and not use an Edit control at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, of course I meant `WM_ERASEBKGND` - it's not something I work with every day so I knew there was a chance I was getting it wrong.  Thanks for the correction.  P.S. manually drawing the text in `WM_PAINT` won't fix it, you still need to erase the old text somehow.  The best way is to tell the underlying window to repaint itself first, but that can get complicated.

Comment: @MarkRansom When the text is updated, I set background of the control opaque. This way the old text is getting erased properly. But I can't make the control repaint itself (transparently) after that. How can I do that?

Comment: As I said, it's a two part process - get the underlying window to repaint that rectangle, that will erase the old text.  Now you can draw the new text with a null brush and transparent background.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'll try this as well. What about the answer I wrote? Can it be developed and be made feasible?

Comment: Note that the edit control (like most of the user controls) does drawing outside of `WM_PAINT` as well. To make a change like this you'd need to repaint the control whenever the text changed.

Comment: @JonathanPotter As I wrote an answer below, I did this by hiding&showing entire window. How can I repaint just the control itself if it's drawn outside of the `WM_PAINT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that once the control is hidden and shown again, it fixes the visibility as intended.

```
case WM_COMMAND:
    if(HIWORD(wParam)==EN_CHANGE)
    {
        ShowWindow(HWND(lParam),SW_HIDE);
        ShowWindow(HWND(lParam),SW_SHOW);
        SetFocus(HWND(lParam));
    }
    break;
case WM_CTLCOLORBTN:
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    SetBkMode(HDC(wParam),TRANSPARENT);
    return LRESULT(HBRUSH(GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH)));
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Why use `GetFocus()`? You know your edit control has focus, and `EN_CHANGE` and `EN_UPDATE` both give you the `HWND` of the edit control in their `lParam`.

Comment: Is it really necessary to have the `if(changing)`?  Seems like it's unnecessary to erase the background if the control underneath has already erased it.